# how to separate define-syntax from syntax-case in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

Consider the following two pieces of Racket code:

```
;version A
(define-syntax (b stx) 
  (syntax-case stx () [(X u) #'(display  (syntax->datum #'(X u v)))]))
(b 1)
```

and

```
;version B
(define-for-syntax (g stx) 
  (syntax-case stx () [(X u) #'(display  (syntax->datum #'(X u v)))]))
(define-syntax (b s) (g s))
(b 1)
```

Experimentally, both programs return `(b 1 v)`. Question:
Is "version B" a valid Racket? If so, is it fully equivalent to "version A"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both of these are fine, and do exactly the same thing, as you've noticed.

Comment: Thank you! The syntax of Racket macros is confusing for a beginner.  I guess `(define-syntax ...)` transforms `(b 1)` into something like

Comment: Thank you! The syntax of Racket macros is confusing for a beginner.  I guess `(define-syntax (b s) (g s))` transforms `(b 1)` into something like `(g (datum->syntax #'(b 1)))` which then gets transformed into `(display '(b 1 v))` and evaluated --- right? My confusion was, I thought `s` would become `1`, subconsciously assuming that `(define-syntax ...)` would behave like `(define ...)`.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, Greg Hendershott's [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/) may help.

Comment: Thank you, Asumu Takikawa. I started reading Greg Hendershott. Very helpful.